# Trying to make a loop statement that changes as with variable

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Here are the instructions to the problem:

Given a non-negative integer, 3 for example, return a string with a murmur: "1 sheep...2 sheep...3 sheep...". Input will always be valid, i.e. no negative integers.

```
def count_sheep(n):
  r = n
  for i in range(n):
            r -= 1
            print(n-r, "sheep...")
```

This is my code, but I need all of the loops to be on the same line and I'm not sure how to make that happen. Could someone please advice how I should use a return statement instead of a print statement to make the loop reiterate and paste the output all in one line? It currently outputs something like:

```
1 sheep...
2 sheep...
3 sheep...
```

but I want it to out put `1 sheep... 2 sheep... 3 sheep...`

Comment: In your case, use `print(n-r, "sheep...", end=' ')`. Also, `r` is redundant. Either use `i+1` in the print statement or `i` and `range(1, n+1)`. Lastly, it seems like the instructions say to _return_ a string, not _print_ it. Are you sure what you're doing is correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can use additional arguments for print function

`end` - end of the string "\n" by default

```
def count_sheep(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(i, "sheep...", end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize string formatting and joining, and list comprehension:

```
def count_sheep(n):
    return " ".join([f"{i} sheep…" for i in range(1,n+1)])
```

Not that this puts spaces only between the parts, not after each part. This conforms to your requirement ("but I want it to output `1 sheep... 2 sheep... 3 sheep...`").